# Selenium (Python) clicking an element within a frame

Tags: python, selenium, linkedin-api, frame

I'm having an issue within LinkedIn. Once you click a "Connect" button, a frame comes up that looks like this: 
[image]

I'm trying to click the "Send now" button, which says it's not visible. I've tried to switch frames by every known id/class. The error says that switching frames cannot be satisfied because the frame cannot be found. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
  <div id="li-modal-container"><div id="ember1954" class="modal-wormhole visible send-invite ember-view"><div aria-labelledby="ember1483-modal-label" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="modal-wormhole-content">
  <div class="modal-content-wrapper">
            <section class="modal">
    <div role="document">
      <header class="send-invite__header">
        <h2 id="ember1483-modal-description" class="Sans-21px-black-85% pv3">
            You can customize this invitation
                  </h2>
          <button type="button" name="cancel" class="send-invite__cancel-btn" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1955="1955">
            <span class="svg-icon-wrap"><span class="visually-hidden">Close</span><li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="cancel-icon"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" height="24px" x="0" y="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="artdeco-icon"><g class="large-icon" style="fill: currentColor">
        <path d="M20,5.32L13.32,12,20,18.68,18.66,20,12,13.33,5.34,20,4,18.68,10.68,12,4,5.32,5.32,4,12,10.69,18.68,4Z"></path>
      </g></svg></li-icon></span>
          </button>
      </header>

      <div class="ph4">
<!----><!---->
          <p id="ember1483-modal-label" class="pv4 mb3 display-flex">
              LinkedIn members are more likely to accept invitations that include a personal note.
                      </p>
<!---->      </div>

      <div class="send-invite__actions">
          <button class="button-secondary-large mr1" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1956="1956">
            Add a note
          </button>
          <button class="button-primary-large ml1" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1957="1957">
              Send now
                      </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

I've tried:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.XPATH("//butto‌​n[@class='button-pri‌​mary-large ml1']")))
```

and get this error: 
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: That's not a frame, that's just a div.

Comment: Are you waiting for the button to be visible before trying to click on it?

Comment: I've tried several different WebDriverWaits... they say "'str' object is not callable"

Comment: Then that's your problem. You need to wait for the element to be visible before you can click on it. You need to show the code you're using and the exact error message.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the additional information. Python code in the comment section is impossible to read.

Answer (score 0):

At least part of the problem is that you are not properly waiting for the element to be visible before trying to click on it.

The code that you're trying to use is incorrect. Your question shows this code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        By.XPATH("//butto‌​n[@class='button-pri‌​mary-large ml1']")))
```

`By.XPATH` is not a function, it is a string constant. When you do `By.XPATH("...")` you are trying to call `By.XPATH` as if it were a function. This is why you get the error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.

The argument to `visibility_of_element_located` needs to be a tuple, where the first value is `By.XPATH` and the second value is the xpath.

For example:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "//butto‌​n[@class='button-pri‌​mary-large ml1']")))
```

If the element is created dynamically, you may need to first wait for the element to exist before you can wait for the element to be visible. You can do that with `EC.presence_of_element_located`.

Comment: Got an error. Message: An error occurred while searching for an element by XPath.

Comment: @ChrisBrocious if that's the entire, precise error message, there's nothing I can do to help you. Bottom line, you need to wait for the element before you can click on it. That is very fundamental to selenium.

Comment: It's quite possible that that element doesn't exist at the time you try to wait for it. You may need to first wait for `presense_of_element_located` before waiting for it to be visible.

Comment: That was all it says. I've had this issue before on LinkedIn with WebDriverWaits... I saw that the driver wasn't waiting for the element to load. I simply timed it out (time.sleep()) and got around it. If you do a simple search of level two connections within LinkedIn you might get a better idea of what I'm fighting with. I figured after the 'connect' click it was a new frame that popped up... I'm new... so

Answer (score 0):

```
def connect_me():
sendNow = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".button-primary-large.ml1")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.visibility = 'visible'; arguments[0].click();", sendNow)
time.sleep(4)
return
```

This was how I was able to get it clicked.